# Python Tkinter Spinbox Validate Fail

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having an issue validating spinbox input.  I have a workaround below that *seems* to work; however, it's awkward.  Assuming this isn't a bug, is there a correct way to do this?  I am using Anaconda Python 3.6 (tk 8.6) on Windows 10.

The issue is that `validate` is set to `None` if you return `False` from the validation function when the value in the spinbox entry is between `to` and `from`.  This only occurs when clicking the up or down buttons and not when directly editing the text.

```
import tkinter as tk

class SpinboxGui:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        vcmd = (self.root.register(self.validate_spin), '%W', '%P')
        self.spin = tk.Spinbox(self.root, from_=0, to=50000)
        self.spin.config(validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.spin.pack()

    def validate_spin(self, name, nv):
        try:
            print(nv)
            n = int(nv)
        except:
            return False
        if n <= 15000:
            return True
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SpinboxGui()
    tk.mainloop()
```

To reproduce, highlight 0 and type 149999.  Then click up a few times.  Note that the validation command stops being called.  Output is:

```
01
014
0149
01499
014999
0149999
15000
15001
```

Now, according to the [docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/spinbox.htm#M26), using `textVariable` and `validateCommand` together is dangerous; indeed, I have [crashed](https://bugs.python.org/issue22810) Python/Tkinter in more ways than one.  However, in this case, it doesn't matter whether you use `textVariable` or not; the problem is the same.

One possible solution might be to edit the `to` and `from` options in the validation function.  Even if this works, it's somewhat problematic for me because I'm syncing spinbox values to an embedded Matplotlib plot.  I would need to compute `to` and `from` and convert units for each Matplotlib Artist and  spinbox.

Since you can't edit the `textVariable` in the validation function, what I came up with is the following.  Maybe someone can improve on this.

```
def __init__(self):
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/4140988/675216
    vcmd= (self.root.register(self.validate_spin), '%W', '%P')
    # Rest of code left out
    self.spin.config(validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)
    self.spin.bind("<<ResetValidate>>", self.on_reset_validate)

def on_reset_validate(self, event):
    # Turn validate back on and set textVariable
    self.spin.config(validate="key")

def validate_spin(self, name, nv):
    # Do validation ...
    if not valid:
        self.spin.event_generate("<<ResetValidate>>", when="tail")
    return valid
```

Comment: This statement is false: _"The issue is that validate is set to None if you return False from the validation function..."_ - the validation function will not be set to `None` simply because you return `False`. In fact, the only valid return values are `True` and `False`. Please read and follow the advice here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is considerable time and effort to reproduce a problem.  It's not that I'm too lazy to do it; I thought this might be the intended behavior of the spinbox.  I didn't want to invest the time hunting down a non-existent problem.  But now that I'm informed, here it is.

Comment: Ur code is fine. I just entered 149999 and then click next and get 150000

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with the validation mechanism in spinbox, I gave up on it. Maybe it works the way it was intended to, but I think it is counter-intuitive that it only gets called once. My application uses spinbox to update a matplotlib graph, and I need the data to be an integer in a specified range. I needed the code to catch non-integer entries as well as out-of-range integers. The solution I came up with was to use key bindings instead of the validation mechanism to achieve the desired result. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
class IntSpinbox(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self,
                   parent,
                   borderwidth=kwargs.get('frameborderwidth', 2),
                   relief=kwargs.get('framerelief', tk.GROOVE))
        self.valuestr = tk.StringVar()
        self.valuestr2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.minvalue = kwargs.get('minvalue', 0)
        self.maxvalue = kwargs.get('maxvalue', 99)
        self.initval = kwargs.get('initvalue', self.minvalue)
        self.valuestr.set(str(self.initval))
        self.valuestr2.set(str(self.initval))
        self.label = ttk.Label(self,
                   text=kwargs.get('labeltext', 'No label'),
                   anchor='w',
                   width=kwargs.get('labelwidth', 20))
        self.spinbox = tk.Spinbox(self,
                   from_=self.minvalue,
                   to=self.maxvalue,
                   increment=1,
                   textvariable=self.valuestr)
        self.spinbox.bind('<Return>', self.updateSpinbox)
        self.spinbox.bind('<FocusOut>', self.updateSpinbox)
        self.spinbox.bind('<FocusIn>', self.storeSpinbox)
        self.spinbox.bind('<Button-1>', self.storeSpinbox)
        self.spinbox.bind('<Button-2>', self.storeSpinbox)

        self.label.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X, expand=True, padx=5)
        self.spinbox.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X, expand=True, padx=2, pady=5)
        self.onChange = kwargs.get('onchange', self.doNothing)

    def storeSpinbox(self, event):
        tmpstr = self.valuestr.get()
        try:
            tmpval = int(tmpstr)
        except:
            tmpval = -1000
        if tmpval < self.minvalue:
            tmpval = self.minvalue
        elif tmpval > self.maxvalue:
            tmpval  = self.maxvalue
        self.valuestr2.set(str(tmpval))        

    def updateSpinbox(self, event):
        tmpstr = self.valuestr.get()
        try:
            tmpval = int(tmpstr)
        except:
            tmpstr = self.valuestr2.get()
            self.valuestr.set(tmpstr)
            return
        if tmpval < self.minvalue:
            tmpval = self.minvalue
        elif tmpval > self.maxvalue:
            tmpval  = self.maxvalue
        tmpstr = str(tmpval)
        self.valuestr.set(tmpstr)
        self.valuestr2.set(tmpstr)
        self.onChange()

    def doNothing(self):
        pass

    def getValue(self):
        tmpstr = self.valuestr.get()
        return(int(tmpstr))

    def setValue(self, value):
        self.valuestr.set(str(value))
```

Comment: There's probably numerous ways around it.  The question is if it's behaving as intended or we're just doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably late to the party, but I'll leave it here in case someone needs it. What I did in a similar situation is to do everything I need in the callback for the writing of the variable I linked to the spinbox. Something like:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
my_var = tk.IntVar() # or whatever you need
spin = tk.Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=100, textvariable=my_var)
spin.pack()

def do_whatever_I_need(*args):
    # here I can access the Spinbox value using spin.get()
    # I can do whatever check I 

my_var.trace('w', whatever) #'w' for "after writing"
```

The callback created by the `trace` method calls the given function whith two arguments: the callback mode (`'w'`, in this case) and the variable name (it's some internal tkinter identifyer I've never used). This is why the signature for `do_wahtever_I_need` is `*args`.